# TypeError creating a Discord Bot - JS

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

https://pastebin.com/2C8pWJ5Z

```
            ping(args[1], parseInt(args[2]), (error, reponse) =>{
                if(error) throw error
                const Embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)

                message.channel.send(Embed)
            })
        break
```

*I'm trying to write an ARK: Survival Evolved Server status bot for discord, however when I try to run this, and input both a IP and port, there is an error.*

**TypeError: ping is not a function.**

*Any thoughts or help would be appreciated, I made a similar bot in the past for a minecraft server and it worked fine, however in this setting it doesn't pass being given an ip and port, still passes correct error messages if you do not post an IP/PORT, but doesnt work after that.*

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: What don't you understand about `ping is not a function`? Seems pretty straightforward to me. `ping` seems to not be defined, have you imported all the scripts you need?

Comment: Yes the only thing I believed I needed to install is arkservers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Ark Server API, there is a bot doing what you need.